# Android TransactionTooLargeException selecting image gallery

Tags: android, xamarin, image-gallery, startactivityforresult

I've built an Android application with Xamarin that contains a function that allows users to select an Image.
In some devices it works but in other devices it trows following exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Here's my code.

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);

intent.SetType("image/*");
StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.selectImage)), SELECT_FILE);
```

It shows the chooser and, when I choose "Image Gallery" the exception throws.

Searching on google I found some posts where people suggested to check the dimension of the image passed between two activities but in that case it crashes before the selection of the image.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi , do you have a check with which version of Android device occurs this error and others can not ?

Comment: By the way , I have tested shared code in my Android Device , it works .Due to not own multi device to test , you can explain the detail info about tested device , such as Brand and version model .

Comment: Hi Junior Jiang, I tested this functionality with Huawei P9 lite having Android 6 and it works. It doesn't work with 2 Samsung having Android 8. Could the problem be the Android version?

Comment: Okey , the reason maybe the android phone company modify something . My android device is Android 10 of XiaoMi 9 , also test with a Android 9 simulator , they all works . Then I guess it should be something modified by phone company (Samsung do something difference with other android phones ) .

Comment: Ok, thanks. But do you have an idea about which could be the feature modified by Samsung? However no I'll search on web... :)

Comment: Oh ,sorry for this is unpredictable . Mobile phone manufacturers will not explain these changes in advance, they are often encountered during the development process by developers. Many times this phenomenon may need to be fixed by mobile phone manufacturers. I also hope that will be known publicly .

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, I'm searching for a solution on web.

Comment: Hi Junior Jiang, I solved my issue, read my answer...

Comment: Oh , that's great !  Glad find the solution , it also works for me . Owesome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching on google I found some posts that suggested to manage OnSaveInstanceState event, on the activity, to save bundle.
This event is called when user chooses "Image Gallery".

Following is the event code:

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);

        if (outState != null)
            outState.Clear();
    }
```